# constrained optimal control excluding the optimal state

Tags: optimization, optimal-control, constraints

I don't know if this is a very basic question:

Let's say there is the typical optimal control problem with the cost function
$$J = \int_{0}^{T} \mathcal{L}(x(t),u(t),t)\mathrm{d}t + \Psi(x(0),t=0)$$
with constraint $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t),t)$ and optimal (feedback) control $u(t)$. Suppose there is a (globally) optimal solution $(x^*(t),u^*(t), t^*)$.

Is there a way to search for the 'next best solution' excluding the optimal solution, i.e. putting in an additional constraint where for example the optimal feedback control $u^*(x(t),t))$ is not allowed?

Comment: When would $u(t)$ not be equal to $u^*(t)$? Would it already be when $u(t) \neq u^*(t)$ for one moment in time or should that inequality need to hold for all time. And how big should the difference be, is an infinitesimal small difference ok?

Comment: The inequivalence should hold for all times and the minimal difference could be a constant for example.

Comment: So $\|u^*(t) - u(t)\| > c, \forall t$ with $c$ some positive constant?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is convex then a local optimum is the global optimum. By constraining the control set the next-best solution will either be:

- "bang-bang"
- inexistent, if the problem is over constrained

If, however, the problem is non-convex then there might be multiple local optima and depending on the additional constraints the next-best solution can be:

- totaly different than the previous one (but still satisfying all necessary conditions).
- "bang-bang"
- inexistent, if the problem is over constrained

When you find an optimal solution for a problem that is non-convex, there is no way of saying if it is global or not, it migh already be an alternative solution!

I guess that there are global search methods, but I don't know anything about about those.